# phpmyadmin not access able on client system. error

Tags: phpmyadmin

I am facing below mention problem after installation of wamp server. It is working fine on same server through local host and throug ip and phpmyadmin is working on same server. But when i access wamp server from other system browser wamp server is access able but phpmyadmin showing this error. Forbidden  You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.  Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at crm Port 80

Answer (score 0):

phpmyadmin is only accessible from local machine for security in most default *amp installations.

open your httpd.conf and search for phpmyadmin. If you do not find any security setting, look out for Includes at the bottom of the file. In xampp extras/httpd-xampp.conf is included per default, there you have security settings:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

This directive says matched locations are only accessible from local machine. Take out phpmyadmin to gain access to phpmyadmin from anywhere, it should look like this afterwards:

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
        Require local
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Restart apache to apply your changes. Keep in mind that this is a security risk, especially if you don't use strong passwords for your phpmyadmin.

Also keep in mind that I have a xampp installation on linux. While configuration of apache is the same on all plattforms, the config files might be organized in an other way or define security with other directives.

If you cannot figure it out on your own, please post the content of your httpd.conf file. From there I could help you find the directive which is blocking access to phpmyadmin.

Just to be complete, here you have a link to the official Apache documentation. You can find anything here, but I agree, it is hard to find if you do not know what to search: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/

Good Luck, may the source be with you.

Comment: "If you cannot figure it out on your own, please post the content of your httpd.conf file. From there I could help you find the directive which is blocking access to phpmyadmin."

Comment: ServerAdmin admin@example.com

#
# ServerName gives the name and port that the server uses to identify itself.
# This can often be determined automatically, but we recommend you specify
# it explicitly to prevent problems during startup.
#
# If your host doesn't have a registered DNS name, enter its IP address here.
#
ServerName localhost:80

HostnameLookups Off

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#

Comment: this isn't a working httpd.conf. maybe it is just cut of. Try to edit your question and insert your full httpd.conf (maybe black out servernames if they are currently online accessible)